# How to make a pop-up if multiple conditions are satisfied

Tags: javascript, alert, onmouseover

Is there a way for a pop-up to appear when all divs got 'onmouseovered'?

```
function moveOver(obj)
            {
                obj.innerHTML = "POP!!!"
                obj.style.color = "#ff0000"
                obj.style.background = "transparent"
                if ()
                {
                    alert("There is no circles left!")
                }
            }
```

I basically have 12 circles that pop when you move your mouse over them, is there a way to make a pop-up that says "There is no circles left!" after I hover over the 12th circle?

Comment: Add a class. `document.querySelectorAll(".yourClass").length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the element

```
obj.classList.add("popped");
```

and check the length

```
if (document.querySelectorAll(".popped").length === 12) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the fact that each one gets the mouse over event. You could give each circle a unique class, and then on the mouse over even, you could add a class to mark it.  Then you just check to see if there are none left that aren't marked.

```js
function moveOver(e) {
  let circle = e.target;
  circle.innerHTML = "POP!!!";
  circle.classList.add('popped');
    if (!document.querySelectorAll('.circleClass:NOT(.popped)').length) {
        alert("There is no circles left!");
  }
}
```

```css
  .popped {
    circle.style.color = "#ff0000";
    circle.style.background = "transparent";
  }
```